# Dubious first posts queue review audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Another question in the *"Will you pass that audit"* line. This one's going to be from the first posts queue.

I've been doing some reviews today, one of which was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6754930). The question behind, [local native-iOS time-hack proof background count-down timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629596/local-native-ios-time-hack-proof-background-count-down-timer), seems to be badly written, abuses non-capitalized letters, shows no research efforts, is vague, overly broad and opinion-based to me. A good candidate for closing.

I decided to give it a small chance as it could have collected some potentially valuable answers by editing out irrelevant information, improving English. Luckily, I hit the *edit* button, thus passed this audit. It turned out that this question gathered 13 votes, with 0 votes presented at the audit.

This audit seems kind of too harsh to me. It's only a matter of plain chance that I passed, I would most probably vote to close another question of this flavour next time and fail the audit.

Am I missing something? What would you have chosen for this audit? Could the dubious audits indicate the reason for rethinking the auditing system so that it wouldn't resemble tossing the coin, or this example is simply an outlier?

Comment: I'm not saying it's a *bad* question, but it certainly isn't a *good* question. For the purpose of moving it out of the audit queue, I've given it a symbolic downvote.

Comment: @Kendra Thanks for prettifying the question! For those who'll catch up later, here's [a shortcut](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27629596/1) to the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

I would have chosen "Edit" by a pretty fair margin.

The user:

- Asked to find a specific, *existing* control
- Included appropriate context
- Showed some things they had already tried to use

Its definitely **not** opinion based, and its very clear what they are asking. Someone with more domain knowledge could suggest "too broad" if you had to roll your own and it was a ton of code.

As a reviewer, I couldn't justify closing that question. It is *terribly* formatted, but that was never a reason to close.

Comment: To recite the question: "I'd like to ask the community if someone knows of a way of creating a local native-iOS time-hack proof background count-down timer ... I'd like to have a time-based reward system in my iOS game, which won't be easily hackable". I see this as a red flag for closing as both too broad and opinion-based question. But ok, that's me. Question *is* clear but the description resembles technical requirements for a programming team (that's probably an exaggeration) and the attempted solution is straightforward. I'm no expert in the field, but this question *needs* improvement.

Comment: @skuntsel Oh, it absolutely needs improvement (and I don't know what those 12 upvotes were about). Does it warrant *closure*? Only if you feel its too broad, and my first thought was "There's probably an actual timer class that solves this" (as it turned out there was, at least sort of). Obviously a domain expert may feel dfiferently.